# Avoiding ASCII conversion in serial communication using luars232

Tags: lua, serial-port, ascii

I am using luars233 library for serial communication using Lua. I need to send data bytes without converting them in ASCII form, but the write function of luars232 is converting the data into ASCII before transmission even if I pass it to the function as a number(data type). Please provide possible assistance

Comment: BTW—the character set and encoding Lua uses for string conversion is determined by the locale, which is specific at a point in time to the thread/process/user/OS. (Hint: It is very unlikely to be ASCII unless you made it so.)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked-around the issue by using escape sequence in String datatype e.g. '\2' would pass 0x02 on to the serial port using write function of luars232. But this restricts performing mathematical operations on the data before transmission. Further suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The library takes the data argument and coerces it to a string via [luaL_checklstring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_checklstring) using standard Lua rules. So, if you want complete control over the data, you should pass a string. A Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes.

Certainly, as you have found, a literal escaped character sequence will work.

You can also use the [string.char(...)](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.char) function, which takes a list of zero or more values 0-255 and creates string with those byte values.

If you have a [table sequence](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6) of bytes, you can [unpack](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack) them into a list:

```
local bytes = { 27, 76, 117, 97 }
port:write(string.char(table.unpack(bytes)))
```

So, yes, you do have to convert to a string. But, you can defer that until just before the write call.